# Change details view of iOS or Android without going back to UITableView

Tags: gui-design, mobile, android, mobile-application, ios

We are redesigning our app and the current one you need to hit the back button to view all Divisions to get to a new Division Details page. We are looking for the best UI option to just change the division on this view attached. We are leaning towards a down arrow near the "5th Grade Boys" to open a select list to choose from. Is there another good design up that could be done for iOS and Android?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The back arrow has a different functionality than showing current page content, I don't think it's the best option. The problem is that within the <kbd>Divisions</kbd> section you are changing the title for part of the content of that section when the header should be the section or menu the user is currently in. Below that header, the selected division and the submenu. You only need the **division selector**.

An option could be a scrollable carousel with all possible divisions to choose from:

[image]

Or a simple forward and back buttons beside the current division to move within the division's section:

[image]

#### Update after the comment

If the options to choose from are of a considerable number, a hamburger menu next to the <kbd>Divisions</kbd> menu with the largest possible number of options when displaying:

[image: Hamburger]

Comment: Nice options, but the first one the event could have 30 divisions and having a user go through all those wouldnt be user friendly. I like the bottom one but again if you have 30, and you want to get to the last one from the first that is 30 clicks.  Just not good user experience options when there are alot of options plus that is a database hit every click so that is not good either.

Comment: Answer updated.-

Comment: Thanks, but I never said I wanted to use the BACK arrown. But a DOWN arrow by the division name to show its clickable.